# Only allow URL's specified in routes to be seen in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

If I have a controller called articles, which has a method called view_articles, a user can type in http://example.com/articles/view_articles/some-post and have it return a page.

I have specified a route to be http://example.com/article/post-name. How can I make it so that only the URL specified in the route is visible? Is there a way for articles/view_articles/some-post to show a 404 instead of showing the same page as the route URL?

I am trying to prevent duplication for SEO purposes.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you can't do that in CI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this->uri->segment(n)` as part of the [URI class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) inside of `view_articles` to redirect traffic to your route if the URI contains `view_articles` as it's second segment.

Comment: As an addition, if you use this method, you should use redirect with http response status code 301/308.

Answer (score 4):

You can always make default routing to a 404 page by correctly defining routes in your `routes.php` file:

```
$routes['article/(:any)'] = 'articles/view_articles/$1';

$routes['(:any)'] = 'main/e404';
```

As stated by CodeIgniter user guide:

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

So you can basically define all you want to be seen at the beginning of the file and block everything else on the last line.

As for your main(can be any other) controller's 404 method -

```
function e404() {
    show_404();
}
```

Comment: This is how you do it with little fuss.  however you can just call the show_404 function inside the routes file to display the codeigniter 404 message without having to go through a controller.

Comment: @WillSampson thank you for the tip, didn't know that! But in any case I think it's better to abstract this so it's easier to change things later and to log (if you want logs to be custom) 404's. What else can be used inside the routes file? I never used anything other than routing itself so I want to know if there's anything tasty can be done?

Comment: There is the 404_override route you can use as well to override the show_404 function, accessed like this:
    $route['404_override'] = 'controller/function';

As for other functions i'm not sure.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant using `show_404()` as a closure: `$route['abc'] = show_404();` - something like that, yes, I completely agree on this one

Comment: No that works as well, you can do exactly what you say there with the show_404() function.

 $route['abc'] = show_404();

Will produce a 404 page when navigating to /abc

Answer (score 0):

I'v done that in other tricky way, first of all you should add some code to __construct function in sys/core/Controller.php 
you can check whether the requested url is in routes or not by this code

```
if(!isset($this->router->routes[uri_string()])){
    show_404(); // Or whatever you want ...
}
```