# Codeigniter - custom routes

Tags: codeigniter

Lets say I have a controller 'standard' with an action 'main'.

If I go to www.myapp.com/standard/main it will invoke the main action in the standard controller.

Now if I want to change the URL I go into the routes.php and set sth like the following:

$route['welcome'] = "standard/main";

Now I can visit www.myapp.com/welcome and it will invoke the same action.

However it is still possible to visit www.myapp.com/standard/main. I now have two routes which lead to the same controller action.

Is this the usual way or should I somehow disable the now unwanted www.myapp.com/standard/main route? If so, how would I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is completely for you to decide the default behavior. If you decide to disable the original url, you can write something like

```
$route['standard/main'] = 'standard/404';
```

Or any custom location, it depends on your project and how you wish it should look like, for example you can 'block' any method from being accessed directly:

```
$route['standard/(:any)'] = 'standard/404';
```

But bear in mind, if you route like you did `$route['welcome'] = "standard/main";`, then you should always remember that the function `$this->uri->segment(n)` will show different values, for example if I will go to url *yoursite.com/welcome/123*, the value of `$this->uri->segment(2)` will be `123`, but if I visit the original URL *yoursite.com/standard/main/123*, it's value will change to `main`.

Bear that in mind and decide for yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is a common structure you'll be using, for each action, you can check the segment's in the URL and then redirect appropriately. In the case of going from `standard/main` to welcome, you would have  the following:

```
class Standard extends CI_Controller {

    public function main() {
        if($this->uri->segment(1) == 'standard') {
            redirect('welcome', 'location', '301');
        }
    }

}
```

This would then check the first segment in the URL and if it sees that you've come to this URL, redirect you to the appropriate route. This can then be applied to each action you want to do the same thing for. Supplying a 301 signifies a permanent redirect.

**Update**

Just found a similar (the same?) question: [Only allow URL's specified in routes to be seen in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626700/only-allow-urls-specified-in-routes-to-be-seen-in-codeigniter)